# Loop rename files using lookup table, with 'rename' command

Tags: bash, unix, rename

I'm trying to use a lookup table to rename files in a batch using a while loop.

Here are my filenames:

```
file1_a.txt
file2_a.txt
file3_b.txt
file4_b.txt
file5_c.txt
```

I also have a lookup table, tab-separated (rename.tsv). The first 1st column is the original string, and the 2nd column is the new string.

```
file1  file10
file2  file20
file3  file3
file4  file4
```

The expected output should be changing all the filenames as follows:

```
file10_a.txt
file20_a.txt
file3_b.txt
file4_b.txt
file5_c.txt
```

Here's my bash script. I'm using 'rename' and not 'mv' to make use of regex.

```bash
while IFS='\t' read orig new; do
        origfile="$orig"
        newfile="$new"
        rename -n -v "s/$origfile/$newfile/" *.txt
done < rename.tsv
```

This script produces no output, but also no errors, so it's not clear what I'm doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There are two different commands with the same name `rename`. One is perl-based and
the other is not. If you are surely using the perl-based one, change `IFS='\t'` to
`IFS=$'\t'`. As you may know `-n` is a `dry-run` option. If you want to actually
rename the files, drop it.

Comment: I'm fairly certain mine is unix based since running `rename.ul` produces the same help message as `rename`. Dropping the dry-run option still doesn't produce any output (errors or filename changes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `rename` command is *not* perl based, it doesn't support `"/org/new/"` syntax, which is a perl expression. Please try instead:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r orig new; do
    rename -v "$orig" "$new" *.txt
done < rename.tsv
```

Please note the usage of `$'\t'`, not `'\t'`.
As a side note, your redundant variable assignments seem unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use parameter expansion methods and `mv`:

```
shopt -s nullglob

while IFS='\t' read -u3 orig new; do
    for f in "$orig"_*.txt; do
        mv -i -- "$f" "${new}${f:${#orig}}"
    done
done 3< rename.tsv
```

`mv` is likely to produce an error message on an error.

Refer to the [Bash Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/) for documentation.